# Crash while attempting to remove title bar

Tags: java, android

I have issues removing title bar, my app crashes on a Samsung Galaxy Ace Plus S7500. I tied different ways:

From code

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

From xml

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

My device is running API 10.

Comment: try this theme   `android:theme="@style/Theme.FullScreen"`

Comment: Are you using it in on create method ??

Comment: What is the message when crash?